# Why doesn't the 'syscall' instruction work under Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I have a very basic assembly program that runs in Linux userland:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov edx, 14
    mov ecx, msg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    syscall

    mov eax, 1
    syscall

section .data
msg db "Hello, World!", 0xA
```

However, this doesn't work as it is, but only if I replace the `syscall`s with `int 0x80`. Don't these do the same thing? I know that `syscall` was designed to be lower-latency, but other than that, I didn't think there was a difference. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `sysenter`?  Linux maps a page with the user-space `sysenter` wrapper into the virtual address space of 32bit processes.  This is the VDSO.

Comment: there are so called man-pages you really have to look up. especially about `syscall`, `syscalls` and the syscalls you want to call. you find everything you had to know about there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syscall` works only in x86-64 operating systems and you should put the system call number in `rax` register instead of `eax`.
[See this website for more information.](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/)

Comment: No system call numbers need more than 32bits to represent!!  `mov r32, imm32` zeros the upper32 of the 64bit register.  Writing `mov rax, 231` will just lead to wasted bytes in the machine code, with some assemblers.  (Either `REX.W=1 mov r, imm32` (sign-extending) or worse `REX.W=1 mov r, imm64`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `syscall` instruction doesn't store "return RIP" or "return RSP" anywhere, so these are typically stored in registers in previous instructions before the `syscall` instruction is used.

I suspect that on Linux `RCX` and `RDX` are used for this purpose; and that all the other parameters end up in different registers because of this.

Comment: RCX and R11, actually